# Unable to query with @MapsId and @Id, but works just with @Id

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have 2 entities, say Car and Engine (just example names, but the logic is the same).

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car", cascade = Cascade.ALL)
    private Engine engine;
    ...


}

@Entity
public class Engine {
    @Id
    private Long id; // 1

    @MapsId // 2
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id") // join column is optional here
    private Car car;
    ...
}
```

So, then I do:

```
em.save(car); // successfully saved, data is in the database, but (see below)
TypedQuery<Engine> query = em.createQuery("select engine from Engine engine where engine.car = :car", Engine.class)
query.setParameter("car", car);

query.getResultList();
```

throws exception:

```
ERROR [main] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:234) - No value specified for parameter 1.
 WARN [main] (TestContextManager.java:409) - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener     [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@17e5cbd] to process 'after' execution for test: method , exception [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query]
```

However, if I change Engine entity to have only @Id on the car instance itself (removing //1 and changed // 2 to @Id) it works.

According to the JPA documentation it should work the same way (at least I expected).

My environment: PostgreSQL 9, Spring framework 3.1, Hibernate 3.6.8.Final, Tomcat 7 (JPA support is added by Spring instrumentation).

**Update**:
I've tried both mappings with EclipseLink and it worked. So the problem is somewhere with Hibernate, probably. Still have no idea how I can force it to work with Hibernate.

Comment: What happens if you remove the JoinColumn? It seems contradictory to me to have both a JoinColumn and a MapsId. The first one says: use a dedicated column, and the second one says: use the same column as the ID.

Comment: Nothing will happen. JoinColumn in this case is optional and it is used to set \@Column for \@Id field. If it is missed, then default @JoinColumn implicitly is used, and so default column name for \@Id from the default \@JoinColumn is used. I really feel that this probably bug in the Hibernate, not sure of course, until somebody proves this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assume the Id you are working with composite keys in the Engine class based on that.
@MapsId only is used when you have an @EmbeddedId, as the following example.

> If the dependent entity uses an embedded id to represent its primary
>   key, the attribute in the embedded id corresponding to the
>   relationship attribute must be of the same type as the primary key of
>   the parent entity and must be designated by the MapsId annotation
>   applied to the relationship attribute.

```
@Embeddable
public class DependentId {
  String name;
  long empPK; // corresponds to PK type of Employee
}
@Entity
public class Dependent {
  @EmbeddedId DependentId id;
...
// id attribute mapped by join column default
  @MapsId("empPK") // maps empPK attribute of embedded id
  @ManyToOne Employee emp;
}
```

As per your code example.

```
 @Embeddable
    public class NewKey{
      private Long id;
      private Long carId; // corresponds to PK type of Employee
    }

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car", cascade = Cascade.ALL)
    private Engine engine;
}

@Entity
public class Engine {
    @EmbeddedId NewKey id;

    @MapsId("carId") // 2
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id") // join column is optional here
    private Car car;
    ...
}
```

Assuming your tried to use the parent key of the relationship as your new key

> If the dependent entity has a single primary key attribute (i.e, the
>   relationship attribute or an attribute that corresponds to the
>   relationship attribute) and the primary key of the parent entity is a
>   simple primary key, the primary key of the dependent entity is a
>   simple primary key of the same type as that of the parent entity (and
>   neither EmbeddedId nor IdClass is specified). In this case, either (1)
>   the relationship attribute is annotated Id, or (2) a separate Id
>   attribute is specified and the relationship attribute is annotated
>   MapsId (and the value element of the MapsId annotation is not
>   specified).

In that case your configuration should work as you can see below, that was tested using hibernate 4.3

[image]